# Realtime data connection between backend and frontend

Tags: ajax, django

I have built a website (using Django) which depends upon realtime data. Now this data is fetched from 3rd party sources at arbitrary intervals (can be 5s 7s, 15s,.. but less than 40s). Now when user logs in my website, the frontend makes an AJAX call at 10s time interval irrespective whether I have new data or not.

Now I am trying to find a way, so that whenever my backend database gets new data, the frontend would "somehow" knows about it and update the result.

I need some guidance on this "somehow", How can this be implemented.

Appreciate your guidance.

Comment: You can use server pushing, search for reverse-ajax or Comet.

Comment: Is data from 3rd party sources fetched by Django?

Comment: Yes, data from 3rd party is fetched from django.